# Why is there a unit argument to the haskellwiki prime numbers implementations

Tags: haskell, wiki, primes

What the title says.

Example excerpted from the haskellwiki prime numbers page:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 -fno-cse #-}
primesTME () = 2 : ([3,5..] `minus` join [[p*p,p*p+2*p..] | p <- primes']) 
  where
    ....
```

What is the purpose of the `()` argument? The code seems to work fine without it. My guess is that it has the effect of forcing the list of primes to be recalculated for each application, but why would that be desirable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you want to have a persistent list of 1000000+ primes in the Memory that you only need at a later point and that eats 8MB of RAM? If not, use a dummy arg and some flags to avoid sharing.

Comment: Ah, yes. forgot the space, just thought about the time required. Thanks.

Comment: You mention flags: Is the fno-cse necessary for not keeping the list in memory? Is the `()` somehow considered a common subexpression, or otherwise affected by the flag?

Comment: @Boris: If CSE is done, the extra argument might have no effect at all.

Comment: And what if I *did* want that? Then I would just say `primeList = primesTME ()` and keep `primeList` around?

Comment: @MatrixFrog That would be one way.